# Swift multiple callback parameters in clousure

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift5

I have this generic method which fetches a document from `Firestore` and returns the document or an error in case it fails. I'm trying to pass two parameters as callback parameters in the closure.

The problem occurs when I try to call it.

```
fetchDocument(documentReference: documentReference) { (_, Error?) in
   //
}
```

Instead of getting `Document?` all I get is an underscore. I do get `Error?` as I should but I do not get `Document?`

I want to get `(Document?, Error?)` instead of `(_, Error?)`

Any idea why?

```
func fetchDocument<Document: DocumentProtocol>(documentReference: DocumentReference, completion: @escaping (Document?, Error?) -> Void) {
    documentReference.getDocument { (document, error) in
        if let document = document, document.exists {
            completion(Document.init(document: document), nil)
        } else {
            completion(nil, error)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by “get”? Why are you using  both the type name _and_ .init? You only need one.

Comment: I removed .init thanks. I want to get (Document?, Error?) instead of (_, Error?) when I call the method.

Comment: The underscore is just the code completion way of expressing that this is a generic parameterized type.

Comment: So It menas my code is ok? I just have to replace the underscore with a parameter name?

Comment: The underscore is a generic representation.  You need to pass in your specific document type, not the _.  The only requirement is that conforms to DocumentProtocol

Comment: FYI, returning two optionals is not "the modern way" - You can use [Result type](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/articles/161/how-to-use-result-in-swift)

Comment: @Paulw11 thanks I will check it